# Flutter - ListView images disappear too early while scrolling, physical iOS device only

Tags: ios, listview, caching, flutter

I have an app that uses a ListView.builder which constructs cards with images using CachedNetworkImage pointed to s3 bucket images.

The issue, is that on physical iOS devices only, the images suddenly disappear once the image is about halfway offscreen while scrolling, but immediately reappear if you scroll back up. 
This has clunky, jarring effect, and is inconsistent with behavior everywhere else.

This setup works perfectly on Android device, Android emulator, AND iOS emulator, but my physical iPhone XR has an issue while scrolling.

I took 10-second videos of the scroll behavior on each platform:

(iPhone XR)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GDPd8oLcqQdOQrfYnyknLSzjiyfBZJSe

(galaxy s8)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gJ7WLRI0IzJNwQCro-RMqHVxbcRtJ6xo

The following code is for each image, although the problem persists even when using different widget such as a basic Image.network:

```
FadeInImage(
  placeholder: MemoryImage(kTransparentImage),
  image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(recipe.imageURL),
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

This issue does NOT occur on iOS emulator.

This problem does not seem to happen with pictures smaller than ~500kb, but I seem unable to get the size of images taken with the camera any smaller than 1mb.

I tried lowering the captured image quality as low as possible (0):

```
File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source, imageQuality: 0);
```

I also tried upping the ListView.builder cacheExtent:

```
ListView.builder(
  cacheExtent: 10000,
  itemCount: recipesList.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return new RecipeCard(
      recipe: recipesList[index],
      inFavorites: userFavorites.contains(recipesList[index].id),
      onFavoriteButtonPressed: _handleFavoritesListChanged,
    );
  },
),
```

Flutter doctor shows all systems good.